# $serviceUrl: Caught Exception: Missing serviceUrl configuration value

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am creating a RequestReport in a PHP script.

I seem to be stuck with an issue for the $serviceUrl - which is giving me the good ol' fashion

> "Caught Exception: Missing serviceUrl configuration value. You may
>   obtain a list of valid MWS URLs by consulting the MWS Developer's
>   Guide, or reviewing the sample code published along side this library.
>   Response Status Code: -1 Error Code: InvalidServiceUrl Error Type:
>   Request ID: XML: ResponseHeaderMetadata: "

Am I using the correct Url below?
$serviceUrl = "http://mws.amazonaws.com";

I have google'd this a few times and have seen one reading:
$serviceUrl = "http://mws.amazonaws.com/Orders/10-01-2011";

Perhaps I am using it wrong...but still a no go.

This works wonders in the MWS Scratchpad, but can't seem to use the correct "endpoint" for my script.

Answer (score 0):

Your urls doesn't work :

http://mws.amazonaws.com/Orders/10-01-2011

http://mws.amazonaws.com/

Try with this url :

https://mws.amazonservices.com/

```
   // Use the endpoint for your marketplace
    String serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/";
```

See here for more explaination :

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html

Pdf guide : ([https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide.*V327338404*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V327338404_.pdf))